# Have result that match condition first

Tags: database, elasticsearch

Given a very simple document:

```
`concert_name` - String containing the name of the concert 
`city` - City ID of the concert
`band` - Band ID
`relevance` - An integer that indicate how important the concert is
```

I want to have all concerts in a specific city but I want first those for a specific band (sorted by relevance) and the all the other sorted by relevance

So I can have query like:

> Give me *all* concerts in `Milan` and return first those for `Pearl Jam`

How can I do this in Elastica 1.X ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

I think this can be done with [sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) on multiple fields and using [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting). You would have to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting). I am assigning value of 10 to the band you would like to match and others get value of 0. Try something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "city": "milan"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "if(doc['band'].value == 'pearl') {10} else {0}",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "relevance": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am assuming higher number means more important concert. I have tested this on `ES 1.7`

Does this help?

Comment: Yes but this doesn't return those for a specific band first.

Comment: relevance is not tied to band? I mean every band would have its own relevance, right?

Comment: No. Relevance is tied to a concert. So concerts for the band I specify in the query are returned first (and sorted by relevance) then all the other concerts for the city sorted by relevance too.

Comment: I have updated my answer after understanding your comment, is this what you want?

Comment: Looking at the query it seems like the right one. Gonna check it before accept the answer.